# Persisting an XML element in eXist-db with CDATA content

Tags: serialization, xquery, cdata, exist-db

I put the following in an xquery module `declare option output:cdata-section-elements "xquery";`  while trying to save a document.  The element xquery is in the xpath `/group/schedules/schedule/xquery` and the element did not save as a CDATA.  What am I missing?

Comment: The discussion in https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/issues/2233 may provide some useful troubleshooting advice.